# Get selected (current) list item ID

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to get a current list item ID using JavaScript?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var docurl = document.URL;
    var beginindex = docurl.indexOf('?ID=') + 4;
    var endindex = docurl.indexOf('&Source=');
    var itemid = docurl.substring(beginindex, endindex);    

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this function: GetUrlKeyValue("ID")

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

       var itemid = GetUrlKeyValue("ID")  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this is the easiest way

```
SP.ScriptHelpers.getDocumentQueryPairs()["ID"]
```